# How to save blob url data in a directory

Tags: javascript, php, audio, blob, recording

I am working on the audio record. Now I want to save that recorded audio in our local directly. When I record audio it is returning blob URL like:

blob: http://example.com/7737-4454545-545445.

When I hit this URL it plays recorded audio. Now I am sending that blob URL from js to PHP script to save your local directory but it is not working.

How can I do that?

Comment: It's not helpful if you don't post your code and tell us exactly what is not working(JavaScript not sending?php not receiving?file not saving? Saved but not readable?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Blob URL` lifetime is linked to `document` which created `Blob URL` from `Blob` or `File` object. `Blob URL` cannot be posted to server as reference for a `Blob` stored at [snapshot state](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#snapshot-state). See [Blob URL Store](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#BlobURLStore).

You can use `fetch()`, `Response.blob()` to get `Blob` representation of `Blob URL`, post `FormData` to server.

```
// `blobURL` : `"blob:http://example.com/7737-4454545-545445"`
fetch(blobUrl).then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => { 
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("fileName", blob, "file.ext"); // where `.ext` matches file `MIME` type  
  return fetch("/path/to/server", {method:"POST", body:fd})
})
.then(response => response.ok)
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Above code is giving following error-  TypeError: HEAD or GET Request cannot have a body.

Comment: See updated post. Set `method` to `"POST"` at `init` object passed at second parameter. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch

Comment: In PHP script  I am getting $__FILES element. For upload i am using following code. But instead of audio file it simply save file named blob. 
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
if($_FILES['fileName']){
 $target_path = UPLOAD_DIR . basename( $_FILES['fileName']['name']); 

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileName']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
  echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['fileName']['name']). 
  " has been uploaded";
 } else{
  echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";

How can I get audio file here?
 }
}

Comment: Try setting file name including extension at third parameter to `FormData.prototype.append()` `fd.append("fileName", blob, "audio.ogg"); // or appropriate .ext for MIME type of file`

Comment: Apologies for the edit! It was on the wrong post :o Please edit back I’m on my phone abroad sorry about that!